# Deploying Symfony2 app on azure causing 404 error (Oops! An Error Occurred The server returned a "404 Not Found".)

Tags: php, symfony, azure, web-config

**Backgorund**

I'm fairly new in symfony application development.

A fresh copy of symfony (version 2.8) is installed and deployed through git to azure. App is running in a subdirectory (i.e http://mydomain.azurewebsites.net/btrfly/). Everything works fine and I can browse it (url: http://mydomain.azurewebsites.net/btrfly/web/app.php). As suggested in symfony tutorial [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/deployment/azure-website.html#configure-the-web-server) I would like to cut out `web/app.php` from the url.

**Problem**

When I add `web.config` file in the `btrfly` folder with the configuration code given in the above mentioned symfony tutorial, it gives me following error:

> Oops! An Error Occurred
>
> The server returned a "404 Not Found".
>
> Something is broken. Please let us know what you were doing when this
>   error occurred. We will fix it as soon as possible. Sorry for any
>   inconvenience caused.

I have checked `app/logs/prod.log` for details and found out following error:

> [2015-12-30 14:43:50] request.ERROR: Uncaught PHP Exception
>   Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "No
>   route found for "GET /btrfly/"" at
>   D:\home\site\wwwroot\btrfly\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener.php
>   line 176 {"exception":"[object]
>   (Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException(code:
>   0): No route found for \"GET /btrfly/\" at
>   D:\home\site\wwwroot\btrfly\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener.php:176,
>   Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\ResourceNotFoundException(code:
>   0):  at
>   D:\home\site\wwwroot\btrfly\app\cache\prod\appProdUrlMatcher.php:48)"}
>   []

P.S. 1. I have cleared prod cache.

2. checked `php app/console debug:router`. there is a route for `subdir` which point towards `/`.
3. `routing.yml` seems fine.

So completely lost for couple of days. Surfing everywhere on web if there's a possible way out. Don't know what's going wrong. Any sort of help or point of direction is highly appreciated.

**Edited**

```
    D:\home\site\wwwroot\btrfly>php app/console debug:route
 -------------------------- -------- -------- ------ ----------------------------------- 
  Name                       Method   Scheme   Host   Path                               
 -------------------------- -------- -------- ------ ----------------------------------- 
  _wdt                       ANY      ANY      ANY    /_wdt/{token}                      
  _profiler_home             ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/                        
  _profiler_search           ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/search                  
  _profiler_search_bar       ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/search_bar              
  _profiler_purge            ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/purge                   
  _profiler_info             ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/info/{about}            
  _profiler_phpinfo          ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/phpinfo                 
  _profiler_search_results   ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}/search/results  
  _profiler                  ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}                 
  _profiler_router           ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}/router          
  _profiler_exception        ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}/exception       
  _profiler_exception_css    ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}/exception.css   
  _twig_error_test           ANY      ANY      ANY    /_error/{code}.{_format}           
  home                       ANY      ANY      ANY    /                                  
  btrfly                     ANY      ANY      ANY    /btrfly                            
 -------------------------- -------- -------- ------ ----------------------------------- 


    D:\home\site\wwwroot\btrfly>php app/console router:match /btrfly


 [OK] Route "btrfly" matches                                                                                           

+--------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
| Property     | Value                                                   |
+--------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
| Route Name   | btrfly                                                  |
| Path         | /btrfly                                                 |
| Path Regex   | #^/btrfly$#s                                            |
| Host         | ANY                                                     |
| Host Regex   |                                                         |
| Scheme       | ANY                                                     |
| Method       | ANY                                                     |
| Requirements | NO CUSTOM                                               |
| Class        | Symfony\Component\Routing\Route                         |
| Defaults     | _controller: AppBundle:Default:btrfly                   |
| Options      | compiler_class: Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCompiler |
+--------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: What do you mean with "checked php app/console debug:router. there is a route for subdir which point towards `/`"? According to the log you need to have a route that points to `/subdir`.

Comment: @xabbuh sorry my bad. yes I meant yes it points to `/subdir`. still same error. any guess?

Comment: Can you show the output of `php app/console debug:router <routename>` where `<routename>` is the name of that route? And can you please also show the output of `php app/console router:match /subdir`?

Comment: As you can see in the output of the router commands there is no route handling requests to the `/subdir` path (the path for the route named `subdir` is `/`).

Comment: @xabbuh problem is still the same. i think it's better to use real names for better understanding. I'm copy pasting exact output this time.

Comment: @xabbuh i have updated even real url of the app. you can check.

Comment: Did you run the command with `--env=prod`? Maybe some of the routes are only loaded in the dev environment of your application (and the exception message shows that you access your application in prod).

Comment: @xabbuh yeah ran with `--env=prod`. btw when i enter this `http://urcity.azurewebsites.net/btrfly` it works. but when i put `http://urcity.azurewebsites.net/btrfly/` it shows me `404 error`. difference is trailing slash. how to set multiple route for a single controller action? e.g multiple route for `indexAction()`. or may be regular expression for setting route?

Comment: You may want to introduce a redirect for requests with trailing slashes like described in the cookbook: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/redirect_trailing_slash.html